# How can I put videos in ListView.builder Flutter

Tags: flutter, video

I am newbie in flutter, trying to put picked videos in a ListView or GridView. How can I put compressed videos in ListView.builder with the code below  :

```
  Future<void> _videoPicker() async {
    if (mounted) {
      final file = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (file?.path != null) {
        final thumbnail = await _flutterVideoCompress.getThumbnail(
          file.path,
          quality: 50,
          position: -1,
        );

        setState(() {
          _videoImage = thumbnail;
        });

        final resultFile = await _flutterVideoCompress.getThumbnailWithFile(
          file.path,
          quality: 50,
          position: -1,
        );
        debugPrint(resultFile.path);

        assert(resultFile.existsSync());

        debugPrint('file Exists: ${resultFile.existsSync()}');

        final MediaInfo info = await _flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
          file.path,
          deleteOrigin: false,
          quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality,
        );
        debugPrint(info.toJson().toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [Listview.builder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists) you need a List to make listview form it, or you can use just [Listview Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) to manually make your Listview

[ListView Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)